Cannot understand how this topology is non Hausdorff
Consider the following topology over $\mathbb{R}$: $\tau = \{\emptyset, \mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R}\setminus [0, 3], [0, 3]\}.$
I cannot understand why this is non Hausdorff. I read here around that a general example of non Hausdorff topology (over $\mathbb{R}$) is like $T = \{\mathbb{R}, \emptyset, U \subset\mathbb{R}, V\}$ where $U$ is open and $V = \mathbb{R}\setminus U$ is finite.
From here I get that the topology I have written fits, since $\mathbb{R}\setminus [0, 3]$ is open and $[0, 3]$ is finite.
Yet I don't understand how to show this is non Hausdorff, unless it's trivial and I got lost in nothing, which means that $\forall x\neq y \in X$ (here $X = \mathbb{R}$), $\exists U_1, U_2$ open neighbourhoods of $x, y$ respectively such that $U_1 \cap U_2 = \emptyset$.
I tried to choose $U_1 = (-10, -5)$ and $U_2 = (4, 8)$. They are both open, their intersection is empty, but according to this choice, $V_1$ and $V_2$ (the complements of $U_j$ are not finite, so they wouldn't be good. I think I am rather confused.
Also, I was reading my professor notes, where he indeed makes such an example of non Hausdorff topology (the one I wrote at the beginning), saying that a sequence like $x_n = (1, 1, 1, 1, \ldots)$ would converge to any point in $[0, 3]$. How is this possible? Thank you if you can explain me in simple terms...

The interval $[0,3]$ is not finite.  It contains an infinite number of points.

Also, the sets $(-10,-5)$ and $(4,8)$ are not open sets in the topology you have given.  There are only four open sets in that topology:  the empty set, the entire set of real numbers, the interval $[0,3]$, and the complement of that interval.  There are no other open sets.

Take any two points $x_1$ and $x_2$ that are both in $[0,3]$.  The only open sets containing one of them are $\mathbb R$ and $[0,3]$, and they are not disjoint.

Be very careful about what topology is being considered.  The topology given in the problem is
$$ \tau = \{ \varnothing, \mathbb{R}, [0,3], \mathbb{R}\setminus [0,3]\}. $$
That's it.  The normal topology on $\mathbb{R}$ has been completely thrown away.  Intervals of the form $(a,b)$ are not open, and singleton sets are not closed.  None of the usual intuition regarding real numbers is applicable.
To show that this space is not Hausdorff, choose any two points in the interval $[0,3]$.  It is impossible to find a pair of disjoint open sets, each of which contains one of those two points:

$\varnothing$ contains neither of those points,
$\mathbb{R}$ contains both of those points,
$[0,3]$ contains both of those points, and
$\mathbb{R}\setminus[0,3]$ contains neither of those points.

Since those are all of the open sets in this topology, the problem is done.
This argument is basically the same argument needed to show that $(x_n) = (1,1,1,\dotsc)$ converges to any point in $[0,3]$.  If $L \in [0,3]$, the game is to show that if $U$ is some open set containing $L$, then there is some $N$ so large that $n > N$ implies that $x_n \in U$.  Again, this can be done by exhaustion:

If $U = \mathbb{R}$, then take $n = 1$.  For all $n > 1$, $x_n = 1 \in \mathbb{R}$.
If $U = [0,3]$, then take $n=1$.  For all $n > 1$, $x_n = 1 \in [0,3]$.

There are no other open sets which contain $L$, so conclude that if $L \in [0,3]$, then for any open sets $U$ containing $L$, there exists some $N$ so large that $n > N$ implies that $x_n \in U$.  That is, $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = L$.  In other words, $(1,1,1,\dotsc)$ converges to every point in $[0,3]$.
